# Not loading the ID in real time

Tags: c#

I want to display the ID that has been inserted into the database in the Combo-Box.

But after I input the data the ID does not load automatically.

The ID appears when I restart the application. Please help me.

This my code loadID

```
public void loadDistributorID()
{
    perbaruiDistributor();

    conn.Open();

    cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "select id from distributor";

    var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read()) {
        if (reader == null) {
            return;
        } else {
            cbDistributor.Items.Add(reader.GetString("id"));
        }
    }

    conn.Close();
}
```

`perbaruiDistributor()` is a method to clean text in textBox and also to read data from the database table.

Comment: do you re-bind the combo-box after saving. if you do, it should work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't say the type of the control. Are you using Winforms or WPF?

Try adding `cbDistributor.Refresh();` after the `while` loop. If that does not work, look on MSDN help about your control, for something to redraw the combobox.